# Find the distribution of $ X $ and $X + Y$

Tags: probability-distributions

$f(x,y) = \exp(-2(x+y))$ , $0<x<y$, and $0$ otherwise.

Find the joint distribution of $X$ and $X+Y$. My attempt consists of letting $ U = X + Y$ and then having $f_x,_u(x,u)=\exp(-2u)$ , $0 < x < u$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Almost correct (in fact $x< u/2$), but just by a coincidence: the transform $x\mapsto x, y\mapsto x+y$ is a bijection with Jacobian equal to $1$. In general, you should find the inverse transform and divide the resulting density by (the absolute value of) its Jacobian.